# Unable to load autoload.php

Tags: drush

I've looked through all similar issues reported but none of them solves my problem. I always install drush with composer and installing 6.4.0 is working just fine, but when I install dev-master then I get the error

`Unable to load autoload.php. Drush now requires Composer in order to install its dependencies and autoload classes. Please see README.md`

Composer is at the latest version.

When I go to ~/.composer I never get a ./vendor/ directory as suggested by answers to other questions.

My environment is Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm using PHP 5.5 - any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: How have you installed Drush?

Comment: Using composer following these steps: composer global require drush/drush:dev-master and then composer install

Comment: And you installed it with the same user you're currently logged in as?

Comment: Can you provide your `composer.json`?

Comment: The composer.json just contains {
    "require": {
        "drush/drush": "dev-master"
    }
} and I have tried both, installing it as the current user and as root.

Comment: The reason why Drush isn't working is certainly because the vendor/autoload.php file is missing. It is nowhere on my machine and regardless which way I try to install, it never exists. I have now copied /usr/local/share/autoload.php to /usr/local/share/drush/drush/vendor/autoload.php and adjusted the path, then it works. So, the remaining question is why composer install doesn't create that file automatically.

Answer (score 3):

you might try running "composer install" from inside your drush directory.